# javafx thread limit to 32?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

**Is javaFX limited it's maximum number of threads?**

I made a javaFX demo:

https://gist.github.com/arnesacnussem/a049f0761c0db9844d19e2d639dcccff

It's meant to use `Service` to create animate by `updateValue()`

Each `AutoMoveCircle` has 3 `service`,

at line 23,I create 20 of it,but only 10 of them shows up in the `pane`

Each service has it's own thread ,there's only 31 service thread

and a `JavaFX Application Thread`,so totally there is 32 thread.

Is there's a limit? how can i change that?

Comment: Note that `Service` has an [`executor`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#executorProperty) property which you can set to make it use your own `Executor` with a greater thread count.

Comment: @Slaw that's much batter than create a new thread pool ,alos could make me not focus on those threads left after fx thread end.Thanks

Comment: I do recommend using a [`AnimationTimer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) instead of several services:simply check,if an update is neccessary based on the difference between the time of the last update and the time passed to the`handle`method.This should work without any issues as long as you do not add any more expensive updates.It furthermore avoids using a ton of threads + synchronisation that probably puts a higher strain on the javafx application thread than simply doing all the calculations on the application thread the way I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Service`'s internal executor has a thread pool limited to `32` threads. Alternatively, don't use the `Service` class. Instead, create a new executor and submit your `Task` objects to it. Something like:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
Task<Paint> task = new Task<Paint>() { ... }
executorService.submit(task);
```

Comment: Sure you can create your own `ExecutorService` and use it directly, but you could also set the [`executor`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#executorProperty) property of `Service`.